# BASH evaluation output redirect

Tags: bash

I want to redirect the output of an expression (of an 'if' statement) into a file. E.g. I want to redirect the output of './primitives' into a file, where the expression of the 'if' statement is './primitive', something like :

```
if ./primitives 1>> output.txt ; then
  echo "primitives OK. " | tee -a output.txt
fi
```

The above won't work, so starting from :

```
if ./primitives ; then
  echo "primitives OK. "
fi
```

how do I get the output of './primitives' into a file, and then only echo the string "primitives OK. " if './primitives' executes correctly?

For a bonus point, how would I redirect only STDOUT of './primitives' appended to file 'output.txt' if it executed correctly, then print "primitives OK. " to both the console and the appended to the file? But if './primitives' didn't execute correctly, don't print anything to 'output.txt' and just print STDERR to the console?

Or am I looking at this whole problem the wrong way?

Thanks

EDIT:

Current script and output is :

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ./compile.sh; then
  echo "Compile OK. " | tee output.txt

  if ./primitives 1>> output.txt ; then
    echo "primitives OK. " | tee -a output.txt
  fi

  if ./composites 1>> output.txt ; then
    echo "composites OK. " | tee -a output.txt
  fi

fi
```

Current console output:

```
Compile OK.
```

Desired console output:

```
Compile OK. 
primitives OK. 
composites OK.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is fine; you just need to ensure that `output.txt` exists first. You have two options: use `>` instead of `>>` (the 1 is unnecessary, as standard output is redirected by default if you don't give a file descriptor), or execute `touch output.txt` before your `if` statement to create the file if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Is the output of `primitives` being appended to `output.txt`? If so, it appears `primitives` is exiting with a non-zero exit code, preventing the body of the `if` statement from executing.

Comment: `primitives` is executing correctly exiting with a zero code, however echo isn't being outputed in output.txt or the console, so maybe I've used `tee` wrong? any idea? I'll have a google. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's a misuse of `tee` because when I comment the pipeline out and leave just `echo`, still nothing is output to neither the console and output.txt.

Comment: What happens if you say `if ! ./primitives 1>> output.txt ; then` instead?

Comment: `./primitives` is returning non-zero, but it still appears to be executing correctly, must be something else wrong. ty anyway

Comment: Ahah it is working now. Thanks, needed to change my c. Thanks

Comment: It appears my lack of confidence in my bash skills was hiding a subtle bug I over looked in C. Thanks again.